# Como puedo enviar el result en el formData en compressor js?, sirve normal pero no envia la imagen comprimida, sinó la imagen normal

Tags: javascript, php

este es el index js, donde uso la libreria compressor js, pero no envia la imagen que quiero al files-hanldler.php

```
  window.addEventListener('load', function (){



    document.getElementById('image').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
      const file = e.target.files[0];

      if (!file) {
        return;
      }
      
       new Compressor(file, {
        quality : 0.3,
    
        success(result) {
    
          const formData = new FormData();

          formData.append('file', result);

    
             axios.post('uploads', result).then(() => {
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open("POST","files-handler.php",true);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    xhr.send(result);
                    console.log(result)
              });                      
                          
        },
        error(err) {
          console.log(err.message);
        },
      });
    });

 })
```

aqui mi files-handler.php

```
<?php

include "db.php";
include "class.upload.php";


error_reporting(0);

    
// $data = array();
$files = array();

foreach ($_FILES['image'] as $k => $l) {
 foreach ($l as $i => $v) {
 if (!array_key_exists($i, $files))
   $files[$i] = array();
   $files[$i][$k] = $v;
 }
}
  foreach ($files as $file) {
    $handle = new Upload($file);
  
  if ($handle->uploaded) {
    $handle->Process("uploads/");
    if ($handle->processed) {
      // usamos la funcion insert_img de la libreria db.php
      insert_img("","uploads/",$handle->file_dst_name);
     

    } else {
      echo 'Error: ' . $handle->error;
    }
      header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
      header('Content-type: application/json');
      $response = array(
        'message' => 'Insercion Completada.',
        'success' => true
      );
      header('Location: index.php?&res='.json_encode($response));


  } else {
    echo 'Error: ' . $handle->error;
  }
  unset($handle);
  }

  
?>
```

y aqui mi index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>UPLOAD</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fomantic-ui/2.8.8/semantic.min.css">

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fomantic-ui/2.8.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>



<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<h1>Subir imagen</h1>
<form id="upload_image" method="post" action="files-handler.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <!-- <form id="formulario"> -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputFile">Imagen</label>
    <input name="image[]" required type="file" id="image" multiple accept="image/jpeg" />

  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Subir imagen</button>
</form>
<span class="statusMsg"></span>
<div id="image_list"> </div>
 

   <?php if (isset($_GET['res'])): ?>
    <?php 
    
    $string =  $_GET['res'];
    $resultado = json_decode($string);
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    echo $data;
     ?>
    <script>
       $('body').toast({
         class: 'info',
         closeIcon: 'left',
         message: '<?= $resultado->message ?>',
        })
    </script>
  <?php endif?> 
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
   $.get("image_list.php","",function(data){ 
                            $("#image_list").html(data); 
                        }); 
</script>


<script src="index2.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/compressorjs'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Todo funciona, pero al momento de hacer el POST envia las imagenes sin comprimir, siendo que según en la variable "result" del index.js ya la tengo comprimida, no se que error tengo.
ya he visto la libreria y he seguido los pasos pero al momento de enviar los datos en el formData envia simplemente las imagenes normales y no las que realmente quiero enviar.

Comment: Creas un `FormData` con el archivo, sin embargo, en las dos peticiones AJAX (axios.post y xhr) envías otra cosa diferente. ¿Son necesarias las dos peticiones?... No creo.

Comment: la variable **result** es la que contiene la imagen comprimida, es decir reducida de tamaño, esa es la que debo enviar a **files-handler.php**, pero no me funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Como te decía en comentarios, estás creando un objeto `FormData`, pero no lo usas en las dos peticiones que, de hecho, solo necesitas una y, en su lugar, envías el recurso obtenido del compresor.

Ante cualquier duda, recuerda siempre consultar la [documentación oficial](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/compressorjs/blob/main/README.md) y revisa los comentarios en el código para saber qué hace cada cosa.

```
new Compressor(file, {
    quality : 0.3,
    success(result) {
        // Crear objeto FormData
        const formData = new FormData();
        // Agregar archivo a objeto con tres parámetros
        // El primero es el nombre que esperas recibir en $_FILES
        // El segundo es el contenido del archivo
        // El tercer es el nombre y es necesario, según la documentación
        formData.append('image', result, result.name);
        // Solo una petición enviando el objeto creado
        axios.post('files-handler.php', formData).then(data => {
            // Mostrar resultado en consola
            console.log(data);
            // Si quieres que se vea en pantalla, aquí puedes hacerlo
        });                      
    },
    error(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    },
});
```

Con estos cambios en Javascript, solo necesitas un par de cambios en PHP, para evitar la redirección, que no va a funcionar; mejor envía un mensaje, por ejemplo: `echo 'Inserción exitosa';` que es lo que se va a mostrar en la consola.

Ten en cuenta que el archivo comprimido se sube sin necesidad de pulsar en el botón de envío (`submit`) y mucho me temo que si estás recibiendo el archivo sin comprimir es porque pulsaste ese botón.